# Jquery - loop animation inside .hover event

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I can't understand why my loop animation doesn't work:

```
        <div id="area_list" class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <h2>
                le nostre aree di pratica
                </h2>
                <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                    <li class="first_in_row">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="img/list_arrow.png" alt="list_arrow" width="10" height="16" />
                            Lorem ipsum
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="img/list_arrow.png" alt="list_arrow" width="10" height="16" />
                            Lorem ipsum
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    function movimento_avanti() {
        $('#area_list li a img', this).stop().animate({
            'margin-left': '5px',
            'margin-right': '0'
        }, 500, function() {
            movimento_indietro();
        });
    }

    function movimento_indietro() {
        $('#area_list li a img').stop().animate({
            'margin-left': '0',
            'margin-right': '5px'
        }, 500, function() {
            movimento_avanti();
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#area_list li', this).hover(function() {
            movimento_avanti();
        }, function() {
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is the selectors inside the funcions, if I put the selector directly in the .hover event(writing the content of the function) it works. Otherwise, if I put just the function (like the code I wrote) it doesn't work... it looks so strange for me...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove both of the references to `this` in your existing code. ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dh9cug1p/))

**However**, I assume that you only want the animation to trigger on the hovered element rather than *all* of the images? In which case you need to pass the jQuery `$(this)` object between your functions. See numbered comments below:

Update:

I'll try to explain.

1. pass the jQuery `$(this)` object as a parameter to your `movimento_avanti` function
2. store `$(this)` in variable called `el`
3. use `el` to scope your selector to the hovered element
4. Pass the stored `$(this)` reference to `movimento_indietro`
5. store passed `$(this)` in variable called `el`
6. use `el` to scope your selector to the hovered element
7. Pass the stored `$(this)` reference back to `movimento_avanti`
   .. repeat for ever

```js
function movimento_avanti(el) { // <-- Passed to here - "el" (2)
    $('a img', el).stop().animate({ // <-- use `el` to scope your selector (3)
        'margin-left': '5px',
        'margin-right': '0'
    }, 500, function() {
        movimento_indietro(el); // <!-- pass along again here - "el" (4)
    });
}

function movimento_indietro(el) { // <-- Passed to here - "el" (5)
    $('a img', el).stop().animate({ // <-- use `el` to scope your selector (6)
        'margin-left': '0',
        'margin-right': '5px'
    }, 500, function() {
        movimento_avanti(el); // <!-- pass along again here - "el" (7)
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#area_list li').hover(function() {
        movimento_avanti($(this)); // <-- SEE HERE (1)
    }, function() {
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="area_list" class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <h2>
                le nostre aree di pratica
                </h2>
                <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                    <li class="first_in_row">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="list_arrow" width="10" height="16" />
                            Lorem ipsum
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="list_arrow" width="10" height="16" />
                            Lorem ipsum
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The animation will run indefinitely. Is that what you really wanted?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your solution, but the 'a img' elements, moves all together, I would the animation to trigger just the hovered element. Than the new code:

Comment: That's what my code does. Only the hovered element animates.  Be careful when you mouse over, it's easy to hit them both

Comment: You haven't done as I suggested. Look at each of the numbered comments.  You need to pass a reference with each function call. See the `el` used each time a function is called

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I tried your code, but 'li' elements moves all.
I would the animation to trigger just on the hovered element.
Than the new code:

```
        <div id="area_list" class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <h2>
                le nostre aree di pratica
                </h2>
                <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                    <li class="first_in_row">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="img/list_arrow.png" alt="list_arrow" width="10" height="16" />
                            Lorem ipsum
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="img/list_arrow.png" alt="list_arrow" width="10" height="16" />
                            Lorem ipsum
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
```

function movimento_avanti(el) {

```
$('a img', el).stop().animate({

    'margin-left' : '5px',
    'margin-right' : '0'

},500,function() {

    movimento_indietro();

    });
```

}

function movimento_indietro(el) {

```
$('a img', el).stop().animate({

    'margin-left' : '0',
    'margin-right' : '5px'

},500,function() { 

    movimento_avanti(); 

    });
```

}

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('a.rss-item').attr('target', '_blank');


$('#area_list li').hover(function() {

    movimento_avanti($(this));

}, function() {



});
```

});